# How to preserve pinned tabs in Edge browser?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I visit a certain website almost every time I open my web browser, and I pin that tab to easily re-visit it. The problem is, when I close Edge, the tab is lost.

How can I pin a tab, and save the pinned tab after closing Edge?

Here is what I have tried and considered, but didn't work out.

- Bookmark it. There are certain advantages (like Ctrl+1 hotkey) to pinning vs bookmarking,
  so I would not like to bookmark it.
- Save the open tabs. No, because sometimes the last tabs I had open were my online banking, or other things that I don't want to pop up automatically.
- Use Chrome (or Firefox, or ...). No, because, although I do use Chrome elsewhere and love it, this laptop is meant to be wiped clean every so often (sometimes every month) and I don't want to keep installing other software over and over.
- Search for a how-to on another site. I read the top 3 google results, and I tried some other unsuccessful searches on MS sites.
- Search here. I looked through some other questions, but didn't find any that addressed this specifically.

EDIT: i learned that in general the pinned tabs are preserved. Normally my question wouldn't make sense, but I seem to have stumbled on one edge case where pinned tabs are lost - when your start page is set as a new tab and your new tabs are set as empty tabs. I set a different start page and now my pinned tabs are preserved. If anyone has more info on this I would happily still accept an answer. But for now I achieved the functionality I wanted and found an answer to my question.

Comment: So, when you say "pin".... are you talking about the "set these tabs aside" feature?

Comment: Tumbleweed badge, baby!

Comment: Pinned tabs are different from set aside tabs because pinned tabs stay visible. If you right click a tab (where the site's favicon and title are) you should get the I option to pin it. If you click that, the tab will move to the left of all non-pinned tabs and become shorter, just showing the favicon.

Comment: I thought I am the only one. My pinned tab keeps getting lost.